# Exact solution of $u_{t}=a_{1}u_{xx}+a_{2}\Phi(t)u_{x}^{2}$, where $\Phi(t)$ is cdf normal

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The PDE for $(x,t)\in \mathbb{R}\times (0,1]$ is

$$u_{t}=a_{1}u_{xx}+a_{2}\Phi(t)u_{x}^{2},$$

where $a_{1},a_{2}$ are constants and $\Phi(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{t} \phi(\frac{x-0.5}{0.2})$. I picked $0.2,0.5$ bc I need $\Phi(0)\approx 0$ and $\Phi(1)\approx 1$.

The IC is $u(x,0)=logcosh(x)$.

**Attempt**

If $\Phi(t)\equiv 1$, then $u(x,t)=log\phi(x,t)$ where $\phi$ solves the heat equation with IC $cosh(x)$. Also, in that case $u_{x}=v$, where v satisfies the Burgers equation. So we have a solution when $\Phi=constant$.

Heuristic: By splitting $[0,1]$ into n subintervals, where for $t\in I_{k}$ the $\Phi(t):=a_{k}$ constant, we get n solutions that we patch together.

Another handwave approach: assume $u(x,t)=TX=\frac{X(x)}{\Phi(t)}$ and $\Phi,X>0$:

$$\frac{T_{t}}{T}=\frac{X_{xx}+X_{x}^{2}}{X}=k. $$

So for various k we want the solution to $LX=X_{xx}+X_{x}^{2}=kX$. For k=0 we get $X=log(x+c_{1})+c_{2}$.

Any suggestions for $k\neq 0$?If you don't mind I will make a separate post for this particular ODE. Thanks

Comment: Why do you think there would be an exact closed form? You can do what you're suggesting to get an approximation, but that wouldn't be the full solution, indeed it probably wouldn't even have the right smoothness properties to make sense as a strong solution.

Comment: You can't really patch *per se*, that's what I was trying to say. The equation where you replace $\Phi$ with a piecewise constant approximation is a much "weaker equation" in the sense of the regularity of its solutions.